# 'pipwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python

It is showing like this:

```
'pipwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

.
How to solve this issue i am beginner please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install [Your packagename]
```

Or
Add Path of scripts to environment variable

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts
```